# Updating array based on newer objects in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question that is hard to describe. It's a tale of two arrays.
I have one array holding 50 objects. Per object, I want to call its specific property `"IDnumber"`.

The second array is one that has 5 variables containing all of the mentioned 50 objects's `"IDnumber"` property, with each variable having a set of 10 IDnumbers: `var1` is the IDnumbers of the first 10 objects, `var2` is is the IDnumbers of the second set, and so on until the 50th object's ID number.

This is where it gets hard. 
If I want to add in a new object in the first array, so that there'll be 51 objects, then I want to update the second array with a 6th variable, that contains all the remaining objects' IDnumbers (in this case just the 1). I want array2's length to be dependent on array1's length.

```
var arr1 = [], obj = {"IDNumber": "1"};
//this is an example array, all objects have the same ID here, but not in my real array
for (var i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
  arr1.push(obj);
}   

var var1 = [arr1[0]["IDNumber"], arr1[1]["IDNumber"], arr1[2]["IDNumber"], arr1[3]["IDNumber"], arr1[4]["IDNumber"], arr1[5]["IDNumber"], arr1[6]["IDNumber"], arr1[7]["IDNumber"], arr1[8]["IDNumber"], arr1[9]["IDNumber"]];
//the other remaining possible variables.

var arr2 = [var1, ...]; //No clue as how to take that on
```

How do I do that? How do I create an array that updates itself with newer possible variables like that? Each variable must have a max of 10 objects' IDnumbers.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. `arr2[0]` is a reference to the same array that `var1` refers to, not a copy of the array. If you modify the array, you'll see it in both places.

Comment: So if you do `var1.push(something)`, you'll see this at the end of `arr2[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `array1` contains your array of objects. The other one is `array2` containing an array of arrays, each sub array has length 10 like you stated

You can split `array1` into groups of 10 and put in `array2` like this

```
function slice10(arraysOfObject) {
    var array2 = [];
    var leftOver = arraysOfObject.length % 10;
    var groupsOfTen = (arraysOfObject.length - leftOver)/10;
    for (var i = 0; i < groupsOfTen; i++) {
        array2.push([]);
        for (var j = i*10; j < i*10 + 10; j++)
            array2[i].push(arraysOfObject[j]["IDNumber"]);
    } 

    //now take care of the leftover
    if (leftOver > 0) {
        array2.push([]);
        for (var i = groupsOfTen*10; i < arraysOfObject.length; i++)
            array2[array2.length-1].push(arraysOfObject[i]["IDNumber"]);
    }
    return array2;
}
```

Comment: Great help, thank you. So `array2` is all the arrays from `array1` that can be divided in groups of 10, and I can access each group of it by its [element] number . But if I add in more objects, I'll have to manually call for those groups. How I do story all groups of those arrays inside 1 array so I don't have to and that it'll be automatic?

Comment: Hi. I've wrapped everything in a function so you can call it to regroup your 1st array when new objects are added. So basically, you have to regroup everytime you add a new object. If you don't want to do that, have a look at the other answer, but  beware of the side-effects of that answer though. Always strive for function purity

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function to deal with adding an object to the two different data structures, and use that function also for adding the first 50 objects:

```js
function addObject(arr1, arr2, obj) {
    if (arr1.length % 10 == 0) arr2.push([]);
    arr1.push(obj);
    arr2[arr2.length-1].push(obj.IDNumber);
}

var arr1 = [], arr2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
  addObject(arr1, arr2, {"IDNumber": i + 1000}); // some dummy ID value
}

console.log(arr2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```